# Electric field of dipole antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, dipole, antennas

I have seen that the electric field of a dipole antenna detaches and propagates.

For a section of the detached electric field, will the antenna experience recoil if the detached field moves a charged object?
[image]

Comment: I don't think the charge would move in a particular direction, it would oscillate in place.

Answer (score 1):

In the farfield where the E-field is propagating as a transverse EM wave, it will interact with your charged particle causing the particle to move in the direction of the E-field. Because of this, the particle is itself accelerated and will as a result emit its own EM wave, back in the direction of your dipole. This will take time to arrive but when it does I believe it will transfer momentum to your antenna. It's not recoil as such but it is a force backwards due to the presence of the charge.

In the near field it is more complex.

Comment: Please be more specific about how that partial emits it’s own em wave. 

By the way in this case the particle (object) would be pushed down in this instance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).